# Warhammer 40K Primarch Vulkan Alive?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Can anyone provide me confirmed and **CANON** examples that may explain something i read on a wiki?
Yes i know a filthy heretical wiki that can be edited by myriad traitor scum.

http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Vulkan#Rebirth

In this parcel of text it is said that after the Salamanders chapter recover Vulkan's body and drop him in a volcano for closure, hoping he would revive, a sergeant immolates himself as a sacrifice. After this a few Salamanders searching for the lost sergeant come across Vulkan himself, spear still in his chest...   And i can find no mention of what happens afterward.

I know that at the close of 'Vulkan Lives' he is plummeting from space onto a planet in Ultramar after teleporting away from his capture by Conrad Kurze following the dropsite massacre where all but his helmet was thought lost.

It is confirmed that he is a perpetual so he may have survived the fall to the planet presuming there was anything left to regenerate from.

Im dying to know, what became of Vulkan?! Is he alive? active? MIA? whats the deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are another novels ([The Unremembered Empire](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18143885-the-unremembered-empire) and [Deathfire](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25111238-deathfire)) set after Vulkan Lives.
In theese novel he is still dead and nobody has tried vaporising his body yet.

Nik Kyme has hinted that more novels about this will come.

**YES** Vulkan is a perpetual and it is clearly demonstrated that he does come back in the previous novels. Konrad has killed him so many times and Vulkan has come back again and again. Just remember that he has a piece of a spear touched by the emperor embedded in his body and that is keeping him full on dead.

Immolate the body and Vulkan can potentially resurrect.

Answer (score 5):

There are no new novels yet in the Horus Heresy that feature Vulkan after he is reborn. The order of books you want to read to cover all this is:

- Vulkan Lives

> Set after the Dropsite Massacre, All the Salamanders find is his helmet, while Vulkan is a prisoner of Curze. At the end we find out he is a perpetual and he teleports away and appears over a planet

- The Unremembered Empire

> Set on Ultramar believing Terra has Fallen, Roboute Guilliman has called his remaining loyal brothers to his side in an aim to rebuild the Imperium with Ultramar as its capital. During the Novel something falls from space and takes out a building, when investigated Vulkans body is found and brought to his brothers, believing him dead they armour him and intern him. When he awakens though his mind is damaged from travelling unshielded through the warp and he goes on a rampage hunting down Curze who is also on Ultramar. We find out that the Cable is trying to kill Vulkan permanently the only way to do this is with the  Fulgurite, a petrified bolt of the Emperor's own psychic abilities but it needs to be used by another Primarch.

- Deathfire

> Set after the events of the previous novel, the Salamanders leave Ultramar with Vulkan's body to return it to their home world of Nocturne with the hope that the flames of Mount Deathfire will restore him. At the end of the Novel Vulkan's body is dropped into a Volcano, believing he was wrong the space marine we have been follwing walks out into the desert, when his fellow Salamanders go searching for him they find Vulkan, with the Fulgurite still in his chest.

Comment: The text i read appears to be set on mount deathfire. Has this not actually happened? As i can find no mention of the events of the text anywhere else on the internet

Comment: That happens at the end of Deathfire. Updated the text with some more info on it.

Comment: Are there any sources for what happend to him after?

And since its a horus heresy book, where the hell is he/has he gone since?

Comment: Not yet. All we know from 40k lore after this he goes to terra but arrives after the fighting, then decides to make some really awesome super cool tech, proceeds to dress up as the easter bunny and hides it all around the galaxy then goes into hiding himself, telling the salamander's if they can find all of his easter eggs he will return.

Comment: How unsurprisingly cryptic of him :L Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the series The Beast Arises, Vulkan is confirmed alive 1,500 years after the Horus Heresy, in addition he is still a perpetual able to return from the dead multiple times.

He is found fighting Orks single-handedly defending the Imperial world of Caldera.

He briefly led the Imperium Forces back to Ullanor and fought the Ork Warboss called The Beast, apparently dying at the culmination of that battle. However he had previously said in this story his return would only be for a short while as he was destined for another war in another time.

He is considered deceased by the Imperium but as his body was never recovered  he may well still be alive waiting to return when the Imperium needs him, or more likely when his return will troll Roboute Guilliman the most :). Given Ullanor became the planet Armegeddon after mechanicum treachery led to them transporting the whole planet across the galaxy just so they could strip it of alien tech. It is very possible Vulkan is buried somewhere on that planet.

<sub>[Black Library, The Beast Arises]</sub>

[Lexicanum, Vulkan, War of the Beast](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Vulkan#War_of_the_Beast)